# Replace comma with period jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace the commas in each `<li>` value with a period.

I have no idea what's wrong with my code.  I checked the console, but nothing...

```
$('#stats li').each(function () {
    $(this).text().replace(/,/g, '.');
});
```

This code should target each `<li>` in `<ul id="stats">`.
Then it should replace each `,` in each `<li>` and replace it with a `.`

I also tried this:

```
$('#stats li').each(function () {
        var comma = /,/g;
        if(comma.test($this)) {
            $(this).replace(comma, '.');
        }
});
```

And I tried this:

```
$('#stats li').each(function () {
    var stats = [];
    stats.push($(this).text());
    stats.replace(/,/g, '.');
    console.log(stats);
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59r3t/2/).

Comment: You need to **set** the `text`. You aren't doing anything with the replaced result (`replace` doesn't replace characters in-place). Try `$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/,/g, '.'));`

Comment: @Ian I think I may have over-thought this...  Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method returns a new string. It does not modify the string in place. Try this instead:

```
$('#stats li').each(function () {
     $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/,/g, '.'));
});
```

But for that matter, jQuery's [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) method accepts a function, too. This is a *lot* cleaner:

```
$('#stats li').text(function (index, text) { 
    return text.replace(/,/g, '.');
});
```